# Join a list of json values using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm attempting to reduce this list of names to a single line of text.

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "speakers": [
        {
            "firstName": "Abe",
            "lastName": "Abraham"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Max",
            "lastName": "Miller"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
Abe Abraham and Max Miller
```

One of the many attempts I've made is this:

```
jq -r '.speakers[] | ["\(.firstName) \(.lastName)"] | join(" and ")'
```

The results are printed out on separate lines like this:

```
Abe Abraham
Max Miller
```

I think the `join` command is just joining the single-element array piped to it (one name per array). How can I get the full list of names passed to `join` as a single array, so I get the expected output shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an array for each speaker that way. What you want is a single array containing all so that you can join them, which is done like this:

```
.speakers | map("\(.firstName) \(.lastName)") | join(" and ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ jq -c '.speakers[] | [ "\(.firstName) \(.lastName)" ]' speakers.json
["Abe Abraham"]
["Max Miller"]
```

If you move your opening `[` you get a single array with all the names.

```
$ jq -c '[ .speakers[] | "\(.firstName) \(.lastName)" ]' speakers.json
["Abe Abraham","Max Miller"]
```

Which you can pass to `join()`

```
$ jq -r '[ .speakers[] | "\(.firstName) \(.lastName)" ] | join(" and ")' speakers.json
Abe Abraham and Max Miller
```

If there are no other keys you can also write it like:

```
$ jq -r '[.speakers[] | join(" ")] | join(" and ")' speakers.json 
Abe Abraham and Max Miller
```